# Retrieve all user identifier information associated with a Crashlytics issue

Tags: crashlytics

I have a Crashlytics issue with a large number of affected users (400+). Our most recent release addresses this issue and I would like to know which users were affected directly. I know Crashlytics displays user information with a particular crash. However, does Crashlytics offer some sort of way to access information in bulk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:
Fabric.io added a new Export id's feature which makes this much easier.

[image: Fabrio.io issue screen shot]

Original:
As a workaround for this issue I built a user script that is run on Tampermonkey on Chrome. While this script can break very easily it currently(12/11/2014) works to skim though all the crashes of an issue and document the username.

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/Slinkkay/9f0f67fac6d1fe45e325)

While not a real answer to the question this at least makes it a bit easier to get the information in question.